# Conditional expectation and variance bertsekas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

> Consider n independent tosses of biased coin, whose probability of heads is random variable $Y$ uniformly distributed in range $[0, 1]$, $X$ is number of heads obtained. Compute $E[X|Y], var(X|Y), var(X), E[X]$

It is intuitive to me that $E[X|Y] = nY$, but when I try to show it using sums

$$E[X|Y] = \sum_{i=0}^{n}i\binom{n}{i}y^i(1-y)^{n-i}$$

I cannot deduce $nY$ from this.

Further for variance $var(X|Y)$ i use:

$$var(X|Y) = E[(X-nY)^2|Y]\\
 \,\,\,\, = E[X^2|Y]-n^2Y^2 = ?$$

Please help in this problem

Answer (score 1):

The mean of Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is $np$ and variance is $np(1-p)$. Ref : https://www.dummies.com/education/math/business-statistics/how-to-find-the-moments-of-the-binomial-distribution/

So $E(X|Y)=nY$ and $var (X|Y)=nY(1-Y)$. Hence $EX =n\int_0^{1} y dy=\frac   n 2$. Can you now find $var (X)$?